# Docusign | Can we add custom field in to the document at specific position through API?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I am trying to add a custom field when I create an envelope and pass the one custom field. Is there any way to add a custom field in the document?
Is there any API Endpoint which we need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some helpful documentation for adding Custom fields to an envelope via the DocuSign API:

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopecustomfields/

For example you can POST to this URL:

```
/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/custom_fields
```

And here's an example Body depending on if you want to use a text custom field or a list:

```
{

"textCustomFields": [
    {
      "fieldId": "sample string 1",
      "name": "sample string 2",
      "show": "sample string 3",
      "required": "sample string 4",
      "value": "sample string 5",
      "configurationType": "sample string 6"
    }
  ],
  "listCustomFields": [
    {
      "listItems": [
        "sample string 1"
      ],
      "fieldId": "sample string 1",
      "name": "sample string 2",
      "show": "sample string 3",
      "required": "sample string 4",
      "value": "sample string 5",
      "configurationType": "sample string 6"
    }
  ]
}
```